# rxjs return result of event inside map

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

hope someone can help I have an observable that returns base64 string inside a map of a http request below

```
transform(url: string, asBase64: boolean): Observable<any> {
        return this.http
            .get(url, {responseType: 'blob'})
            .pipe(map(val => {
                if (!asBase64) {
                    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(val))
                }
                let base64Data = null;
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(val);
                reader.onloadend = () => {
                    base64Data = reader.result; // need to return this! 
                    console.log(base64Data);

                };
            }));
    }
```

The problem is I need to conditionally return the result  `reader.onloadend = () => {`

I guess I need to convert this to a promise and use mergeMap? Not sure how.

**Update**

So had another stab at this.. From the mergeMap docs looks like this should work, debugging I can see the blob being passed to `reader.readAsDataURL(data);` but `return reader.result;` never fires, looks like I'm losing the reference to `reader`

```
transform(url: string, asBase64: boolean): Observable<any> {
        return this.http
            .get(url, {responseType: 'blob'})
            .pipe(map(val =>
                <any>(asBase64 ? val : this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(val)))
            )).pipe(mergeMap(data => {
                if (!asBase64) {
                    return of(data)
                } else {
                    let reader = new FileReader();
                    let eventObservable = fromEvent(reader, 'onloadend').pipe(map(() => {
                        return reader.result;
                    }));
                    reader.readAsDataURL(data);
                    return eventObservable;
                }
            }));
    }
```

Comment: `fromEvent` isn't deprecated (only it's variant with result selector is deprecated) and yes, you have `Observable<Observable<any>>`

Comment: @martin Sorry what I had did not actually work, any idea on how I do this ?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do

Comment: you dont have to pipe/map the eventObservable just return it in the end

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha I need to map because the event firing does not provide any response. I have figured this out now. In the end I had to use a subject as the problem was the onloadend event was firing before the template had subscribed to the observable, a race condition basically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the FileReader onLoadEnd event is asynchronous, so it won't work inside the map function.

One way to solve your problem is to wrap your function with a Promise, create an observable from the promise with [from](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/from.html), and use the [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) operator to map your observable to the new one from the promise.

Now when you subscribe to the resulting observable, it will emit the result from the FileReader. If it rejects you can get the error with the second parameter of the subscribe method.

```
import {from} from 'rxjs'
import {switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators'

transform(url: string, asBase64: boolean): Observable<any> {  
  return this.http
    .get(url, {responseType: 'blob'})
    .pipe(
      switchMap(
        val => from( // create the observable from a promise
          new Promise((resolve, reject) => { //create a new Promise               
            if (!asBase64) {
                resolve(this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(val))) //resolve if base64
            }            
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(val);

            reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result); //resolve when it finishes to load the file
            reader.onerror = () => reject(reader.error); //rejects if there was an error while reading the file
          })
        )
      )
    );
}

...
const file$ = transform(url, asBase64)
file$.subscribe(
   (file) => console.log(file), // do stuff with the file here
   (error) => console.log(error)  // there was an error while reading the file
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured this in the end. So I needed to use `mergeMap` based on the response, and if wanted `asBase64` create a new observable from the `onloadend` file reader event.

But it didn't also quite work becuause of these lines (see the code in my original question).

```
let reader = new FileReader();
                    let eventObservable = fromEvent(reader, 'onloadend').pipe(map(() => {
                        return reader.result;
                    }));
                    reader.readAsDataURL(data);
                    return eventObservable;
```

The problem with the fromEvent approach is that the event only fires once and in my case was firing before my Angular template had managed to subscribe to the observable, the solution was to use a `Subject` not sure if thats ideal in this case but seems ok to me.

```
transform(url: string, asBase64: boolean): Observable<any> {
        return this.http
            .get(url, {responseType: 'blob'})
            .pipe(map(val =>
                <any>(asBase64 ? val : this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(val)))
            )).pipe(mergeMap(data => {
                if (!asBase64) {
                    return of(data)
                } else {
                    let reader = new FileReader();
                    let subject = new Subject<any>();
                    reader.onloadend = () => {
                        subject.next(reader.result);
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(data);
                    return subject;
                }
            }));
    }
```